# cryptsetup cannot close mapped device

Tags: systemd, disk-encryption, luks, device-mapper, udevd

When I run:

```
LANG=C cryptsetup --debug luksClose /dev/mapper/Pool-A

it fails as follows:

    device-mapper: remove ioctl on Pool-A failed: Device or resource busy

Device /dev/mapper/Pool-A is still in use.
Command failed with code 16: Device or resource busy
```

(...) (It repeats a lot of lines like that)

```
# cryptsetup 1.7.2 processing "cryptsetup --debug luksClose /dev/mapper/Pool-A"
# Running command close.
# Locking memory.
# Installing SIGINT/SIGTERM handler.
# Unblocking interruption on signal.
# Allocating crypt device context by device /dev/mapper/Pool-A.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# dm version   OF   [16384] (*1)
# dm versions   OF   [16384] (*1)
# Detected dm-crypt version 1.14.1, dm-ioctl version 4.33.0.
# Device-mapper backend running with UDEV support enabled.
# dm status Pool-A  OF   [16384] (*1)
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sdb1 with direct-io.
# Allocating crypt device /dev/sdb1 context.
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sdb1 with direct-io.
# Initialising device-mapper backend library.
# dm table Pool-A  OFW    [16384] (*1)
# Trying to open and read device /dev/sdb1 with direct-io.
# Crypto backend (gcrypt 1.5.3) initialized in cryptsetup library version 1.7.2.
# Detected kernel Linux 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64 x86_64.
# Reading LUKS header of size 1024 from device /dev/sdb1
# Key length 32, device size 3906961375 sectors, header size 2050 sectors.
# Deactivating volume /dev/mapper/Pool-A.
# dm status Pool-A  OF   [16384] (*1)
# Udev cookie 0xd4d14d3 (semid 917504) created
# Udev cookie 0xd4d14d3 (semid 917504) incremented to 1
# Udev cookie 0xd4d14d3 (semid 917504) incremented to 2
# Udev cookie 0xd4d14d3 (semid 917504) assigned to REMOVE task(2) with flags         (0x0)
# dm remove Pool-A  OFT    [16384] (*1)
```

(...) (It repeats 25 lines alike)

```
# Releasing crypt device /dev/sdb1 context.
# Releasing device-mapper backend.
# Unlocking memory.


I've found that this problem arises when I tri to use udev rules like that:

ACTION=="add",ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="57584E314135364632334141", RUN+="/etc/bacula/openmount.sh A" 
ACTION=="remove",ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="57584E314135364632334141", RUN+="/etc/bacula/umountclose.sh A"
```

This the low level info:

```
[root@backup ~]# dmsetup info Pool-A 
Name:              Pool-A
State:             ACTIVE
Read Ahead:        256
Tables present:    LIVE
Open count:        1
Event number:      0
Major, minor:      253, 3
Number of targets: 1
UUID: CRYPT-LUKS1-2b69b6e48b6d4bd1942ae7505d530f27-Pool-A
```

And block device info is as follows:

```
    lsblk -o +UUID /dev/sdb
NAME       MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT UUID
sdb          8:16   0  1,8T  0 disk             
└─sdb1       8:17   0  1,8T  0 part             
  └─Pool-A 253:3    0  1,8T  0 crypt            48c1accf-47a6-45ec-aacc-6686e8a8a2fa
```

My OS is:

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) with kernel 3.10.0-327.36.3.el7.x86_64

Is it a systemd-udev problem? How can I fix it? Or is that a innocuous warning?

Comment: What is this device used for? Have you unmounted the filesystem before trying to close the LUKS?

Comment: Device is /dev/sdb, is an external usb drive. Yes I unmounted, checked and re-checked with lsof that is not being used.

Comment: 5 years later I have a similar issue, did you ever find a way to list what has a lock?

Comment: same here.. not mounted, no processes holding.. not sure why luksClose doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This is a difference between systemd-udev and classic udev.  systemd-udev mounts in a separate namespace, so mounts in RUN scripts won't be visible to users.  You can try `systemctl restart udev` and if that releases the lock, it's the issue.  To do this correctly, you'll have to work within systemd.   What's working for me is the following: a udev rule to catch the USB drive being plugged in:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?1", ENV{ID_SERIAL_SHORT}=="575...", SYMLINK+="offsitebackup", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}+="offsite-backup.service"
```

This creates a /dev/offsitebackup link pointing to the first partition of the drive and triggers the service.  The service file is:

```
[Unit]
Description=Offsite Backup script
Requisite=dev-offsitebackup.device
BindsTo=dev-offsitebackup.device
After=dev-offsitebackup.device

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/scripts/offsite-backup.ksh offsitebackup
Type=oneshot
StandardOutput=journal

[Install]
WantedBy=dev-offsitebackup.device
```

The script then does luksOpen/mount/copy/umount/luksClose.  Additionally, to test these out, you can simulate unplug/replug of the USB drive with:

```
udevadm trigger -v -c remove /dev/sda
udevadm trigger -v -c add /dev/sda
```

and you can see device/script state within systemd using:

```
systemctl status dev-offsitebackup.device
systemctl status offsite-backup.service
```

Two pages that helped to figure this all out are [here](https://systemd-devel.freedesktop.narkive.com/RNxZVSrL/systemd-udevd-seems-to-kill-mount-ntfs-started-in-rules-scripts) and [here](https://blog.tjll.net/systemd-for-device-activation-and-media-archiving/).